# (ember.js) Get Binding property returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The Code is from the ember.js official introduction:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ember-0.9.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.president = Ember.Object.create({
        name: "Barack Obama"
    });

    App.country = Ember.Object.create({
        presidentNameBinding: "App.president.name"
    });

    App.country.get("presidentName");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to display the return value of `App.country.get("presidentName");`,so i wrapped it with alert, but the alert always display `undefined`. The wired part is if i execute this statement in firebug console, it display correctly which is `"Barack Obama"`.

The official introduction mentioned:

> Note that bindings don't update immediately. Ember waits until all of
>   your application code has finished running before synchronizing
>   changes

Is this the reason why i can't get the value of the binding property in the code?
What does "application code has finished running" actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're playing around with objects that have bindings like this, you have to manually trigger the bindings to sync with `Ember.run.sync()`:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.president = Ember.Object.create({
    name: "Barack Obama"
});

App.country = Ember.Object.create({
    presidentNameBinding: "App.president.name"
});

Ember.run.sync(); // Manually sync bindings

alert( App.country.get("presidentName") );
```

Here's a jsFiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ebryn/3Ctns/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Observer that essentially fires after the initial application code runs.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ember-0.9.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.president = Ember.Object.create({
        name: "Barack Obama"
    });

    App.country = Ember.Object.create({
        presidentNameBinding: "App.president.name"
    });

    App.country.addObserver('presidentName', function() {
        alert(App.country.get("presidentName"));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Look for 'addObserver' in the [ember.js introduction](http://emberjs.com).